# How to convert ASCII values that are substring inside a string to its character

Tags: java

How to convert ASCII values that are substring inside a string to its character? For example:

If I give input as

```
H105 68u100e33 65r101 89o117?
```

I need output as

```
Hi Dude! How Are You?
```

In the above input after every alphabet or spaces there is an ASCII value.

```
char[] a = new char[2];
char t;
String temp,output="";

for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
    a[0]=str.charAt(i);
    a[1]=str.charAt(i+1);
    if(Character.isDigit(a[0])){
        if(Character.isDigit(a[1])){
            String con=String.valueOf(a[0])+String.valueOf(a[1]);
            int n=Integer.parseInt(con);
            output=output+(char)n;
        }else{
            //nothing
        }
    }else{
        output=output+a[0];
    }
}

System.out.println("output : "+output);
```

I have tried something like this, and it fails at 3 digit ASCII values and also sometimes I face array index outofbound error due to `charAt(i+1)` statements.

How to change that ASCII values to its char and form a sentence?

Comment: Will your final sentence always contain alphabets?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your algorithm based on the phrase "Get all the digits first, and then for each one, replace it with its ASCII value"

So,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "H105 68u100e33 65r101 89o117?";
    
    // Get all the digits by replacing the non-digits with space
    // And then split the string with space char to get them as array
    final String[] digits = input.replaceAll("\\D+"," ").trim().split(" ");
    
    // For each one, replace the main input with the ascii value
    for (final String digit : digits)
        input = input.replaceAll(digit, Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(digit)));
    
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern NUM = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "H105 68u100e33 65r101 89o117?";
    String output = NUM.matcher(input)
        .replaceAll(m -> Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(m.group())));
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

output:

```
Hi Dude! Are You?
```

`NUM` is a pattern that matches one or more digits.

`NUM.matcher(input).replaceAll()` replaces all characters that match this pattern in `input`.
 `m-> Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(m.group()))` converts the matched numeric string to an integer and then converts to the string corresponding to that character code.

Comment: Please explain the regex pattern and the answer is perfect.

Comment: @JoopEggen I have added a description for this code.